# How to make routing pages with Angular JS using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to both of Ionic framework and angular js which I find really helpful.

I'm stuck with a tiny problem. I'm not able to make routing pages. I just wanna link two pages dynamically.

on the first page I have a list of friends using `ng-repeat`.

when I click on a list item I want to show another page which contains all the details of the friend selected.

I was confused reading both of Angular js and Ionic documentation. so can you pease help with a simple code.

here is my code :

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/vOXJYx)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
  <ion-content> 
 <div class="list">

  <div class="item item-divider">
    Friends
  </div>

   <a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="item in items">

        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>

</a>   

  </div>
    </ion-cotent>
</div>

<script id="friend.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <view left-buttons="leftButtons" right-buttons="rightButtons" hide-back-button="true" title="'Awesome'">
        <content padding="true" has-header="true">
          <h1>Friend details</h1>
        </content>
      </view>
    </script>
```

Comment: You are missing routing set up (ui-router & states) + calling the nested state with ui-sref

Comment: thanks for your comment ! can you please give an example

Comment: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

I edited your CodePen, have a look. Yes you were missing `$state`, as well as `anuglar.config`. I hope you get clear on how to use states and how to pass data between them.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwJWvO)